# Media Queries: Target retina macbook pro only

Tags: css, macos, media-queries, retina-display

I'm using media queries for my site and it works perfectly from web to mobile.
Now I want to use some styles exclusively Apples Retina MBP's (NOT iPad, iPhone, etc.).
But I can't get it to work, when I change the CSS, it changes only on all devices.

Does anyone know a bulletproof media query only for the Macbook Pros which he tested?

Answer (score 3):

I use this Media queries:

```
@media 
only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) and (min-device-width: 1025px),
only screen and (   min--moz-device-pixel-ratio: 2) and (min-device-width: 1025px),
only screen and (   -o-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2/1) and (min-device-width: 1025px),
only screen and (        min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) and (min-device-width: 1025px),
only screen and (           min-resolution: 192dpi) and (min-device-width: 1025px),
only screen and (            min-resolution: 2dppx) and (min-device-width: 1025px) {

    /* MacBook-Retina-specific stuff here */
}
```

Source: http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/retina-display-media-query/

Answer (score 2):

Media queries don't detect user agents/devices; they detect *features* (such as resolution & orientation). Try using javascript and applying a class to the body, and applying styles from there.

```
var retina = (window.retina || window.devicePixelRatio > 1);
if (retina) {
    $('body').addClass('retina'); // for example
}
```

Then in your css

```
body.retina {
    // styles
}

body.retina #element {
    // styles
}
```

Source: http://hjzhao.blogspot.co.uk/2012/07/detect-retina-display-using-javascript.html

Answer (score 0):

I would try with

```
@media screen and (min-height: (yourtargetdevicepixelsheight)px) and (min-width: (yourtargetdevicepixelswidth)px) {
     you styles here
}
```

As it is Apples Retina MBP's I dont think many devices can have both conditions, you could also lock it adding

```
and (max-height: (yourtargetdevicepixelsheight+1)px ) and the same with 'width'
```

hope it helps